# How do I capture/control ERB warnings about already initialized constants?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that uses the ERB class to parse some embedded Ruby. If the code being parsed redefines a constant, then ERB prints a warning to STDERR, but my script isn't aware of this happening at all.

- How can I discover if a warning has been issued?
- Can I force it to be an error?
- Can I get the warning text before it goes to STDERR and manipulate/redirect it?

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby
  require "erb"
  begin
    erb  = ERB.new("<% FOO = 1 %>\n<%FOO = 2 %>", 0, "-")
    result = erb.result
  rescue
    fail # Doesn't cause exception
  end
  STDOUT.puts "OKAY"
  ```

Output is:

```
(erb):2: warning: already initialized constant FOO
(erb):1: warning: previous definition of FOO was here
OKAY
```

Comment: Redirection is simple. Just do `$stderr = StringIO.new` (or something)

Comment: Looks like erb views this as a warning and therefore doesn't raise an error. Even if you capture stdout and stderr, you may not get anything in your production environment if you set the logging level such that warnings aren't generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergio's tip gave me the ability to do just what I wanted:

```
captured_err = StringIO.new
old_stderr = $stderr
$stderr = captured_err
# Can generate warnings to $stderr
result = erb.result
$stderr = old_stderr
captured_err.close
if (captured_err.size != 0) then
  STDERR.puts "** #####"
  STDERR.puts "** ERROR: Ruby code resulted in warnings"
  captured_err.string.each_line { |line| STDOUT.puts "   " + line }
  exit 1
end
```